# Add description to lightbox image

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, lightbox

I'm using this lightbox plugin: http://s.codepen.io/schadeck/pen/gjbqr

I would like to know if there is any way to add a simple description attribute in my current code.

What I want to achieve is a description text on the bottom of the image in the lightbox. I've looked for a solution, but nothing seems to apply for the lightbox.js script I'm using.

Here is the code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

  // global variables for script
  var current, size;

  $('.lightboxTrigger').click(function(e) {

    // prevent default click event
    e.preventDefault();

    // grab href from clicked element
    var image_href = $(this).attr("href");  

    // determine the index of clicked trigger
    var slideNum = $('.lightboxTrigger').index(this);

    // find out if #lightbox exists
    if ($('#lightbox').length > 0) {        
      // #lightbox exists
      $('#lightbox').fadeIn(300);
      // #lightbox does not exist - create and insert (runs 1st time only)
    } else {                                
      // create HTML markup for lightbox window
      var lightbox =
          '<div id="lightbox">' +
          '<p>Clique para fechar</p>' +
          '<div id="slideshow">' +
          '<ul></ul>' +        
          '<div class="nav">' +
          '<a href="#prev" class="prev slide-nav">Anterior</a>' +
          '<a href="#next" class="next slide-nav">Proxima</a>' +
          '</div>' +
          '</div>' +
          '</div>';

      //insert lightbox HTML into page
      $('body').append(lightbox);

      // fill lightbox with .lightboxTrigger hrefs in #imageSet
      $('#imageSet').find('.lightboxTrigger').each(function() {
        var $href = $(this).attr('href');
        $('#slideshow ul').append(
          '<li>' +
          '<img src="' + $href + '">' +
          '</li>'
        );
      });

    }

    // setting size based on number of objects in slideshow
    size = $('#slideshow ul > li').length;

    // hide all slide, then show the selected slide
    $('#slideshow ul > li').hide();
    $('#slideshow ul > li:eq(' + slideNum + ')').show();

    // set current to selected slide
    current = slideNum;
  });

  //Click anywhere on the page to get rid of lightbox window
  $('body').on('click', '#lightbox', function() { // using .on() instead of .live(). more modern, and fixes event bubbling issues
    $('#lightbox').fadeOut(300);
  });

  // show/hide navigation when hovering over #slideshow
  $('body').on(
    { mouseenter: function() {
      $('.nav').fadeIn(300);
    }, mouseleave: function() {
      $('.nav').fadeOut(300);
    }
    },'#slideshow');

  // navigation prev/next
  $('body').on('click', '.slide-nav', function(e) {

    // prevent default click event, and prevent event bubbling to prevent lightbox from closing
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();

    var $this = $(this);
    var dest;

    // looking for .prev
    if ($this.hasClass('prev')) {
      dest = current - 1;
      if (dest < 0) {
        dest = size - 1;
      }
    } else {
      // in absence of .prev, assume .next
      dest = current + 1;
      if (dest > size - 1) {
        dest = 0;
      }
    }

    // fadeOut curent slide, FadeIn next/prev slide
    $('#slideshow ul > li:eq(' + current + ')').fadeOut(750);
    $('#slideshow ul > li:eq(' + dest + ')').fadeIn(750);

    // update current slide
    current = dest;
  });

});
```

HTML:

```
<ul id="imageSet">
<li><a href="" class="lightboxTrigger"><img src="" title=""></a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

I haven't looked at the script but you could try this:

```
 var desc = ['some description title', 'another description title', 'etc'];

  $('body').append(lightbox);

  // fill lightbox with .lightboxTrigger hrefs in #imageSet
  $('#imageSet').find('.lightboxTrigger').each(function(index) {
    var $href = $(this).attr('href');
    $('#slideshow ul').append(
      '<li>' +
      '<img src="' + $href + '">' +
      '<span>' + desc[index] + '</span>' +
      '</li>'
    );
  });
```

Comment: You're going to need to add some css, but this should work: http://s.codepen.io/anon/pen/vuLyJ

Comment: Im sorry can you insert a COntact Form to post a message maybe?? thanks in advance!!